# Storing IO action result in a LET clause

Tags: haskell

Hello can someone please explain me how do you store in haskell the result of an action in a `let block` if you know you are going to use it from that point on (you need the result like a header) ?

In my case i am calling two times `listDirectory`,i want to save the value of the first call in a variable `initialList` to later compare its length to a later call of `listDirectory`.

How can i store the first call of `listDirectory` in my variable `initialList`?

```
module Main where 

import System.IO
import System.Directory
import DB(db)
import Company

main::IO()
main = do
    putStrLn "Insert folder for output:"
    folder<-getLine
    makeDir folder>>= \b -> 
        putStrLn (if b then "Created" else "Existed Already")

makeDir::String->IO  Bool
makeDir dirname=let root="D:\\"
                    enumerateDirs=listDirectory root
                    initialList=<<enumerateDirs in  //how can i store it here?

     if  dirname `elem` initialList then
        putStrLn "Directory found , folder count:"++length initialList
     else  
        createDirectory root++dirname>>
        length enumerateDirs >initialList
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use binding, rather than `let`/`=`, for IO actions. Like this:

```
makeDir dirname = do
    let root = "D:\\"
    initialList <- listDirectory root
    if dirname `elem` initialList then
        putStrLn ("Directory found, folder count: " ++ length initialList)
    else createDirectory (root ++ dirname)
    finalList <- listDirectory root
    return (length finalList > length initialList)
```

However, this technique for creating a directory has some problems. Because you may not be the only program running:

1. The directory may be created between your first `listDirectory` and your `createDirectory`, causing you to try to recreate a directory that already exists and throwing an exception.
2. Even if directory creation fails for you, another file may be created between your first `listDirectory` and your second `listDirectory`, causing you to return `True` even though you haven't created the new directory.
3. Even if directory creation succeeds for you, another file may be deleted between your first `listDirectory` and your second `listDirectory`, causing you to return `False` even though you have created the new directory.

Additionally, because `dirname` comes from unsanitized user input:

4. The `` dirname `elem` initialList `` check is looking for the wrong directory name in the wrong directory listing if the user input contains backslashes. For example, if the user enters `a\b`, this code will search for `a\b` in the directory listing for `D:\`, when it should be looking for `b` in the directory listing for `D:\a`. The logic of the `length` comparison is similarly incorrect for such inputs.

To fix these problems, I recommend either calling `createDirectory` directly (i.e. with no checks beforehand) and using exception-catching mechanisms to determine whether it failed and whether this is because the directory already exists or calling the existing `createDirectoryIfMissing` instead.

Comment: Could you please provide show me/ tell me where i can find resources for exception handling for Haskell?